# Are fuel cells suitable for missions with high power requirements?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, fuel-cell

Are fuel cells suited for missions with high power requirements?

Comment: Recommended by who?

Comment: In general for a space flight by the respective authorities.

Comment: The fuel cell manufacturers recommend them highly.

Comment: Okay i see the sarcasm :D may I ask why?

Comment: The question is poorly formed. If you ask about recommendations, you need to say by who, or it's not answerable. If you ask if fuel cells are *suitable* for a certain mission, that is answerable. In fact, that is actually what the answers are addressing. You will notice that none say who is "recommending" anything. They discuss suitability. They are good answers, but not to the question you asked.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: Maybe English is not OP’s native language? In my native German asking „Sind Brennstoffzellen empfehlenswert für hohen Leistungsbedarf?“ (“Are fuel cells worthy of recommendation for high power requirements?”) would be perfectly understandable.

Comment: High power requirement yes, high energy requirement no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it lacks details needed to answer the question.  There are 3 other VTC, all claiming opinion-based.  However, if re-written with specific details, I think such a question could be objectively answered.

Comment: @DrSheldon remember the function of closing a question is to prevent anyone from posting an answer. With three well-received answers posted already, it doesn't look like answer-prevention is really beneficial here, and significantly changing the question *after answers are posted* is also something to avoid. Once in a while, a short question is enough to generate good answers, and that's what SE is - good answers to on-topic questions. These are all good answers here, no? Three with combined score +58, no? Voting to **leave this one open**.

Comment: @uhoh: Agreed that closing is moot at this point.  We do indeed have three excellent, informed, well-written answers.  But they each go in their own directions, because the question was too vague.  I'm not sure whether any of them address what the OP wanted (other than one got the checkmark).

Comment: @DrSheldon 1) [@uhoh's lemma #3: Stack Exchange is both a floor wax and a desert topping²](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377004/303080) meaning (in this case) answers are also for *future readers* 2) OP's decision to accept an answer is purely a personal matter between the user and the answer(s) present - [Ours is not to wonder why.](https://goodreads.com/quotes/381355-ours-is-not-to-wonder-why-ours-is-just-to)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Mars missions with continuous high power output requirement are generally not recommended.

The problem with fuel cells is that, while they can provide quite a bit of power, they consume fuel in proportion to that power. And once the fuel is out, they are dead and there's no means to bring them back to life. Sure you could just pack more fuel, but you're then cutting into the mission's mass budget, and soon the solution becomes inferior to the ones currently in use:

Mars missions currently use two types of power sources: RTG (radioisotope thermoelectric generators) and solar panels. Neither can provide high power but both work for a long, long time. And the missions have batteries, which can be charged from RTG or solar power, and provide even higher momentary power than fuel cells for applications that require it (e.g. Perseverance's MOXIE - oxygen production experiment, which requires high temperature and high pressure of the CO2 it converts) - so the experiments can be run intermittently, whenever the battery charge allows - and when it doesn't, just waiting some time resolves the shortage. Thus the batteries fill the gap of "high power" requirements for when it's necessary, and the remainder of the mission doesn't require it.

Sure, both RTG and solar come with their own shortcomings - RTG being very expensive, in very limited supply, and decaying over time, and solar panels being at whims of weather, seasonal changes, day/night cycle, and dust. But the extended lifetime, and the energy total both can provide over their lifetime dwarfs that of fuel cells (with comparable mass budget) - which is a highly sought after trait - and the one gap where fuel cells shine (high power output) is filled with rechargeable batteries.

It is possible further down the line in colonization of Mars, methane or similar fuel cells may become useful for applications like powering fast/heavyweight rovers (for manned exploration and cargo/materials transport), with stationary solar power farms (or a nuclear generator) producing fuel from the atmosphere. But for now, there are simply no mission profiles where the unique advantages of fuel cells would be more valuable than the sum total of energy produced by solar and RTG.

Comment: Couldn't you "recharge" the fuel cell by using solar power (or RTG or whatever) to re-split its waste product (e.g. water) back into its inputs (e.g. hydrogen and oxygen)?  Or is that impractical?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner you could, provided you carry the necessary infrastructure. This is not something the fuel cells are very good at.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner that's called a battery...

Comment: The fuel cells manage to provide better energy density than normal batteries at cost of using very difficult to reverse chemical reactions. All chemical reactions are more or less reversible, but if you try to reverse these utilized in fuel cells, and bundle the "reversing" machinery with the cells, plus storage for the products for reversal (instead of venting them) you're no longer "better off" - at that point just packing enough li-ion batteries is a better option.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner - It'd be more efficient to just use a normal battery...

Comment: I suspect that if we want to do manned missions to mars we may have to at least seriously consider sending fission reactors.

Answer (score 18):

As an addendum to SF's excellent answer, Fuel Cell technology also suffers from many technical issues which discourage use in long-duration missions.

A big one is moving parts: both solar panels / batteries and RTGs can be built using no moving parts in a completely static arrangement. There are no bearings that need to spin, no valves that need to open, etc. This is not the case with fuel cells. They are incredibly dense and complex with many moving parts (valves, coolant pumps, regulators) required to facilitate hydrogen and oxygen flow through the cell(s). Basically, there's a lot that can break.

The next big issue that fuel cells have is thermal management. Since they usually rely on hydrogen and oxygen combining to create water, standard fuel cells cannot be operated at subzero temperatures or in other conditions that don't support liquid water. This means the entire fuel cell system needs to be pressurized and heated/cooled to keep it at the optimal operating temperature (some designs run much hotter or colder, but still need to be regulated).

Generally, the operation of a fuel cell is a very fine balancing act. You need to get a bunch of pressures, temperatures, flow rates, humidity levels, gas concentrations, coolant flows, etc all working in perfect harmonious balance to run the thing, and even a small mistake like a blocked channel in the cell caused by a water droplet can lead to a "meltdown" which permanently destroys the fuel cell and breaks the fragile catalyst inside.

Compare this to a solar panel, which short of being smashed to bits, will simply produce power when pointed at light, or an RTG that produces power by just existing, and there's really no competition.

Comment: Good description of fuel cells! I always felt the ones in the shuttle were minor miracles of mechanical engineering. They regulated their temperature, power outputs, etc, with no computerization at all. Their electrical control box was a bunch of relays like what you'd find in a old pinball machine. They did cut a couple missions short though; once for cause, the other for a sensor problem.

Answer (score 18):

As you can see from the other excellent answers, your question as posed is incomplete.

When asking what kind of power source is appropriate for a mission, the power level is only one variable. Another critical variable is mission duration.

This graph derived from Hyder, [Spacecraft Power Technologies](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/p100#t=aboutBook) and shown in this [Auburn University Space Power lecture material](https://www.eng.auburn.edu/%7Edbeale/ESMDCourse/PaulPenko81109Chapter%209.pdf), shows power source technology versus mission duration and power level.

[image]

From here, you can see that fuel cells are appropriate for *short duration* high power missions, like a Space Shuttle mission.

Other considerations apply, as always: packaging, environment the vehicle will "live" in, and the other members of the Holy Trinity:cost and schedule.

Comment: Odd that the graph's mission duration goes down to seconds.  I'm skeptical that a useful mission could be that short.  Even sounding rockets last longer than that.

Comment: @DrSheldon many graphs start the axis at zero. There probably aren't many zero duration missions - at least by design.

Comment: True, but this is a log-log graph, which can't start at zero.  Anyway, +1 nice answer.

Comment: The X axis isn't really log - it's more descriptive than numeric.

Comment: @DrSheldon Maybe they consider missions also the operation of, say, booster rockets that must burn just for times in the order of tens or hundreds of seconds. I mean, they may have some onboard electronics that must remain on after they are jettisoned until they land? Just a guess, though.